# Why is test returning "ActionController::ParameterMissing" when the param is in fact present?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a controller test that is failing as follows

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing:
param is missing or the value is empty: user

Failure/Error:
       params.require(:user).permit(
         :description,
         :url,
         :published,
         :enabled
         )
```

The test:

```
it { expect {
  post :create, {:user => attributes_for(:user) }
  }.to change(User, :count).by(1) }
```

The controller methods are as follows

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: t('.notice') }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
    end
  end
end
def object_params
  Rails.logger.info params
  params.require(:user).permit(
    :description, 
    :url,   
    :published, 
    :enabled
    )
end
```

The logs show

```
{"user"=>{"url"=>"http://example.com"}, "controller"=>"users", "action"=>"create"}
```

which clearly shows the "user" param is *not* missing or empty.

I can not see why this test is failing? Am I crazy, or have I missed something obvious?

Comment: Have you tried manually passing in the object's attributes `post :create, object: {url: 'http://example.com'}` ? I don't think you're actually creating the object.

Comment: Where is the exception raised? Is it on the `params.require` line?

Comment: You may have a name collision issue if you are trying to use `Object` as an ActiveRecord model. `Object` is also a standard Ruby class. Try using a different model name.

Comment: thanks @zetetic, i think you are correct, I am not creating the object. In fact, the test is failing before the create method is called. The error is raised on `params.require`, I've added to my question. The actual model failing is `User` not `Object`, I had been experimenting with debug code, hence the confusion. Oddly, I am using very similar code and tests elsewhere that are passing without problem. Struggling to see why this is failing

Comment: OK, I finally tracked this down. I had not noticed that this test has a before block which is also calling a `post :create` action, hence the hash I had seen in the logs related to this post event, and the one actually being tested was returning an empty hash. The solution was either change my user factory to ensure attributes are present (previously the factory only set a parent association), or add attributes in line.